# Second edit on the same question doesn't submit with previous latest edits

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, editing, suggested-edits

I edited this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887683/surface-area-of-solid-revolution-by-integration-without-technology) once (edit 1) which was again edited (improved - edit 2) by user1729. I later found a more apt question title and edited the question again (edit 3) just to change the title of the question (without paying attention to the body).

To my surprise, I found that my latest edit (edit 3) was done over my previous edit (edit 1), which included some mistakes that was corrected by user1729. Can you please suggest why this happened because there is no way I can revoke my edit and correct it again.

I want to know if this is how it works or if it's a bug ?

Note: FYI, I edited the question again to  include the formatting (that was lost due to my previous edit) done by user1729.

Comment: Had my edits loaded when you clicked "edit"? Or did you only see them *once* you had clicked edit?

Comment: Yes, they did. I saw your name on the part of the question that shows "edited x mins ago @someone" before I clicked on "suggest edit".

Comment: And yet you submitted yet another edit? Please refrain from editing one post three times.  Do a thorough job of editing, particular when your edits are "suggested edits", else, what will happen, and happened today, is reviewers of suggested edits are forced to go through three edit attempts from you.  So in the future, submit only one edit, or if absolutely necessary, a second edit.  Else, to me at least, with three edit suggestions it looks like you're trying to earn 2+2+2 rep pts for editing one question.

Comment: @amWhy I understand that very well. 3rd edit was not necessary at all, it was just to get back all the lost formatting that happened. I was actually hoping someone would do that in my place. 2+2+2 was never my intention, though it happened and I would keep that in mind, never to repeat it again (however bad the edits be, I would try my best to edit it in a single attempt, if I miss something I'll wait for others to complete that). In case someone doesn't come for a long time, I might go for a 2nd but that would be final.

Comment: It's okay, once in a while, to catch something you missed, and to edit a second time.  That happens frequently enough that it usually doesn't raise eyebrows. I am not in any way questioning your motivation.  I think you made it clear you were trying to correct what a previous edit might have interfered with.  Just don't make it a habit ;-)

Comment: I would never. I understand that there was a lack of concentration on my part too as I have mentioned in my question, while editing the title of the question I **assumed** that the body would have the latest edits so I didn't check it but there we had a problem (which is the theme of this question). So I really thank you for your advice. I'll do better edits from next time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the bug has been fixed (or was a temporary issue) because now when I try to edit, I can see that previous edits have loaded.